# How to respond for discrepancy in Background check?

Tags: new-job, background-check

I've Joined one IT MNC and after 2.5 months they told me that they found some discrepancy in my background verification. My previous employer told them that the documents are correct but the salary is wrong because I mentioned my higher-on-paper salary. Now, my current employer wants me to draft an email for clarification and told me that that mail will decide my job future.

However, I've talked with my previous employer and they told me it happened becuase of miscommunication.

Please anybody help me to draft a solid mail. My career depends upon on one mail now.

Comment: what does "my higher-on-paper salary" mean.

Comment: "My-on-paper salary" means my payslip have higher amount then they told to my current employer

Comment: You might also consider simply showing them your payslip, if you still have it.

Comment: MNC: Multi-national corporation? Please edit.

Comment: I show them payslip but they got different information from my last to last employee.

Comment: This might be deliberate. Was your departure from the previous employer on good terms? It might also be that your previous employer and current employer are competitors, and your previous employer knows that your current employer has a muddled HR department. If you have paper slips or bank statements that show your actual salary, explain to your present employer that's as much as you can give them.  Statements from previous employers are proving to be untrustworthy.

Comment: @MeredithPoor: I show them patylips(Signed by Managing Director) but they answered different during verification inquiry and agreed that Payslip of 12k is valid but it was on demand payslip and actual salary was 8.5 k only. I don't have Bank statements because they paid in case. So,I demanded to provide at least payslip for future references.

Comment: @Dhaval - now you know why 'paper trails' are so important.

Comment: @MeredithPoor : Yes but i knew when left that company so i got payslip of total amount but it seems stand against me now..I thinks its simple thing to understand (they lied) that if x employer told that payslips are valid but it was on demand but actual salary was different. isn't it?

Comment: Any chance your previous employer would clarify the discrepancy in writing for you? Proof is better than an explanation.

Comment: And now you know why I never tell a prospective employer what my current salary is. I tell them how much I want to make and leave it at that.

Answer (score 2):

What you are saying here is that your previous employer provided a wrong (lower) salary when asked, and that they admit they were wrong. That's what your email should say. It would be a much harder email to explain why you falsified your old salary, but if you didn't you don't have a hard email to write at all. I would write something like

> I have spoken to Name at Company and have been assured this is a miscommunication on their part. I assure you my previous salary was X as I stated. You should expect a new letter (email, phone call, fax, ....) from Person at Company by Date.

If you haven't been told that your old company is going to fix the problem then you could replace the last sentence with

> Name has agreed to be contacted by phone at xxx to confirm this information for you.

If nobody at the old company has told you that they are going to send a new letter or that it's ok to phone them, then their claim of "miscommunication" sounds hollow and your priority right now is not writing an email, it's getting someone at your old company to fix the problem that you believe could torpedo your career.

Comment: You may want to revisit the expression "creative glance." I don't think it means what you think it means.

Comment: is fine to send an below email................................As discussed, I understand your concern about background verification and policy. It seems like miscommunication within the My X Employer management. I declare that all the documents provided by me are valid and genuine. However, if possible please do verify the documents again with my X Employer. Thanks, Dhaval

Comment: @AmyBlankenship ?? "Creative glance" is not in my answer

Comment: @Dhaval your comment suggests "ask them again" and is nowhere near as strong as "I talked to Specific Person who says they were wrong and a correction is on the way to you." Also "it seems like miscommunication" is not as strong as "they told me it was a miscommunication". If your position is as you outlined in your question, send a strong email that says so.

Comment: By emails and calls your problem gets resolved than well and good. Otherwise keep handy all documents as a proofs of the Salary credited (bank statement), tax computation sheet (form-16), salary slip and offer letter mentioning CTC.

Comment: AnNd if you can provide a copy of your payslip to prove your salary was what you said, that too is a good idea.

Comment: I've already provided payslips but thing is that Payslip amount is higher than the What my previous employer mentioned in my answer of verification which is real issue now. My Previous X Employer told that Docs are correct but amount mentioned because I've demanded higher amount on payslip. However they paid me in cash and they ready to confirm it now.

Comment: I seriously question the wisdom and/or integrity of any employer who pays you based on what you earned at a previous position.  I would not be comfortable working for anyone who demands a salary history.  It is none of their business, by definition.

Comment: @WesleyLong  : Thanks but now they want me to draft an email which can decide my job future. I don't know what to and how to tell them by email. I've prepared this mail based on my discussion with some senior friends..Mail = "As discussed, I understand your concern about background verification and policy. It seems like miscommunication within the My X Employer management. I declare that all the documents provided by me are valid and genuine. However, if possible please do verify the documents again with my X Employer. Thanks, Dhaval"

Comment: @Dhaval:Somehow, I think if they were happy with your work then this is a non-issue. Maybe once seeing what they got for their money they aren't satisfied. Is that a possibility? If so, then now they are looking for an out. While preparing this "solid mail", I would also be sending out some resumes. It is nice to get as high a salary as you can, but you also don't want to get a higher salary than your skills can justify. Otherwise, your head will be first on the chopping block.